# What is the yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ date/timezone formatting, and how can I replicate it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, iso8601

I am trying to replicate this date-time format:

`2015-11-05T02:53:04.987Z`

I am pretty close using `moment().format()`

Which gives me:

`2015-11-08T14:25:48-08:00`

I've tinkered with this  a bit but don't understand the formatting well enough. What is happening in the first timestamp offered, and how can I replicate that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators *"What is happening in the first timestamp offered?"* `Z`  represents UTC and it equivalent to `+00:00`.

Comment: So it looks like the `.987Z` part is correlated with the `-08:00` part of the second timestamp. Can't seem to find what '`.987Z' represents though.

Comment: No, `.987` are simply the milliseconds. Further up on the same page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times .

Comment: `.987` is milliseconds (padded), `Z` is the UTC/GMT timezone, i.e. `+00:00`

Comment: Right on, thanks guys! I can feel the neurons forming already. :)

Comment: You don't need any library at all, use [*Date.prototype.toISOString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.toisostring).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RobG points out in the comments, `new Date().toISOString()` will get you that format.

You mention that you are using `moment`. If you want to stick with it, [moment's `utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) and [`toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/) will do it too:

```
var moment = require('moment');

console.log(moment.utc().toISOString()); //2015-11-08T22:32:56.729Z
```

Comment: Or without moment.js: `new Date().toISOString()`.